# Get the path of first file in each directory or sub-directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a directory structure as following: The `Root` directory contains some sub-directories in which many`.txt` files are placed or some  `sub-directories` again  that contains different files with the same extension.

```
├───Root
│   ├───SubDir1
        └───file1.txt
│   ├───SubDir2
│   ├───SubDir3
│       └───SubSubDir1
            └───file1.txt
            └───file2.txt
│   └───SubDir4
│       └───SubSubDir1
        └───SubSubDir2
            └───file1.txt
```

I want to save all the first file-paths in each directoriy in a `QStringList`. E.g.:

```
/Root/SubDir1/file1.txt
/Root/SubDir3/SubSubDir1/file1.txt
/Root/SubDir4/SubSubDir2/file1.txt
```

The following code gives me all the file-paths in a directory or sub-directories but not the path of the first file in each.

```
QDir rootFolder("/root");
QStringList list;
QDirIterator dirIter(rootFolder.absolutePath(), QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoSymLinks | 
QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

while(dirIter.hasNext())
{
    dirIter.next();
    if(QFileInfo(dirIter.filePath()).isFile())
    {
        if(QFileInfo(dirIter.filePath()).suffix() == "txt")
        {
            qDebug()<<"File Path: " <<dirIter.filePath();

            list.append(dirIter.next());
            qDebug()<<"List: " <<list;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dirIter.next()` returns already the next value !
The problem is, you skip the first item after your while loop.

EDIT: If you only want the first filename you can do this:

```
QDir rootFolder("/Users/chris/Downloads");
rootFolder.setSorting(QDir::Name);
QStringList list;
QDirIterator dirIter(rootFolder.absolutePath(), QStringList() << "*.txt", QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

QStringList directoryList;

while(dirIter.hasNext())
{
    QString filename = dirIter.next();
    QFileInfo info(filename);

    if(directoryList.contains(info.absolutePath()))
    {
        continue;
    }

    qDebug()<<"File Path: " << info.absoluteFilePath();
    list.append(filename);
    directoryList.append(info.absolutePath());
}

qDebug()<< "List: " << list;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this does not give me the path of the first file in the folder but all the paths of the files.

Answer (score 1):

please consider iterating recursively on root using as filter the file1.txt

example#:

```
QDirIterator it("/home/root", QStringList() << "file1.txt", QDir::NoFilter, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext())
{
    qDebug() << it.next();
}
```

that will print directly a DEbug message like

```
/Root/SubDir1/file1.txt
/Root/SubDir3/SubSubDir1/file1.txt
/Root/SubDir4/SubSubDir2/file1.txt
```

read the doc for more info:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html